# How can I use gulp to replace a string in a particular source file using a config object?

Tags: gulp

How to achieve a replacing a string on a particular source file while the source files will be concatenated.

```
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
rename  = require('gulp-rename'),
concat  = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify  = require('gulp-uglify'),
replace = require('gulp-replace');
var config = {
    cssConcatFiles: [
       'one.css',
       'two.css',
       'three.css'
    ]   
 };

 gulp.task('css-concat', function() {
     return gulp.src(config.cssConcatFiles)
         .pipe(replace('url\(\'', 'url\(\'../images/fancybox/'))
         // I want to perform this replace to a particular file which is "two.css"

         .pipe(concat('temp.css'))
         .pipe(uglyfycss())
         .pipe(rename('temp.min.css'))
         .on('error', errorLog)
         .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/plugins/fancybox'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if)

```
const gulpIF = require('gulp-if');


gulp.task('css-concat', function() {
 return gulp.src(config.cssConcatFiles)

     //.pipe(replace('url\(\'', 'url\(\'../images/fancybox/'))
     // I want to perform this replace to a particular file which is "two.css"

     .pipe(gulpIF((file) => file.path.match('two.css') , replace('url\(\'', 'url\(\'../images/fancybox/')))

     .pipe(concat('temp.css'))
     .pipe(uglyfycss())
     .pipe(rename('temp.min.css'))
     .on('error', errorLog)
     .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/plugins/fancybox'));
});
```

You could use the following pipe instead of the gulp-if call:

```
.pipe(replace(/url\(\'/g, function(match) {
      if (this.file.relative === "two.css") {
        return 'url\(\'../images/fancybox/';
      }
      else return match;
}))
```

since `gulp-replace` will take a function as an argument and provide that function with a vinyl file reference (`this.file`) which you can use to test for which file is passing through the stream.  You must, however, return something from the function call even when you want to do nothing - so return the original match.

I recommend using `gulp-if`, much cleaner in your case.